# Two characters with the same ASCII Code?

Tags: sql, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to clean a recently imported sql server 2008 database that have to many invalid charcters for my application. and I found different characters with the same ASCII code, ¿that is posible?.

If I execute this query:

```
select ASCII('║'), ASCII('¦')
```

I get:

```
166 166
```

I need to do a similar work, but with .net code.

If I ask for these char in .net:

```
? ((int)'║').ToString() + ", " + ((int)'¦').ToString()
I get:
"9553, 166"
```

Anybody can Explain what happens

Comment: Neither of these characters is ASCII - ASCII only goes up to 127 (it's  a 7 bit code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `ASCII`, use the [`UNICODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) function.

Both `║` and `|` are not an ASCII characters, so calling `ASCII` with them would convert incorrectly and result in the *wrong* value.

Additionally, you need to use unicode strings when calling the `UNICODE` function, using the `N` prefix:

```
SELECT UNICODE(N'║'), UNICODE(N'|')
-- Results in: 9553, 166
```

Comment: OK, but, how can I get a with sql a similar result for (int)'...?

Comment: @Ariel Larraburu - `select UNICODE('║'), UNICODE('¦')` will return the correct values.

Comment: No, returns 166, 166. Try it.

Comment: @Ariel Larraburu - My bad. The strings need to be unicode to begin with... `select UNICODE(N'║'), UNICODE(N'¦')` returns `9553, 166`